# AWS Lambda connecting to Internet

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

### TL;TR

I am trying to connect to internet from AWS Lambda, I have a private subnet with a NAT Gateway but still the function cannot connect to internet...

### Full Question

So I am trying to access internet with my AWS Lambda function. I have tried both Java and NodeJS 4 with no luck.

I have a private VPC with a subnet: 10.0.10.0/24

[image]

As you can see I have added a rule to my NAT Gateway:

[image]

I configured my AWS Lambda like this:

[image]

Selecting that subnet (10.0.10.0) and with a security group that is open to everything (both inbound and outbound)

But yet when I try to download something from internet, the lambda times out:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

var http = require("http");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
    console.log('value2 =', event.key2);
    console.log('value3 =', event.key3);

    var options = {
      host: 'www.virgilio.it',
      port: 80,
      path: '/'
    };

    http.get(options, function(res) {
      console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });

    callback(null, event.key1);  // Echo back the first key value
    // callback('Something went wrong');
};
```

> {
>    "errorMessage": "2016-05-10T10:11:46.936Z 79968883-1697-11e6-9e17-1f46a366f324 Task timed out after 55.00
>   seconds"
>    }

Is this a bug?

**Note: the same function works If I don't select my VPC**

Answer (score 90, accepted):

By default, a lambda function is not bounded to a VPC, which enables it to have internet access, but prevents it from accessing resources in a VPC, such as RDS instances.

If you attach the lambda to a VPC, you'll loose internet access, which prevents you from accessing resources such S3 and Dynamo, and from making HTTP requests.

If you need both, then I'll have to set up the VPC for internet access, which is a mess (hey AWS guys, if you have a well-defined process for it, please make it simple: turn it into a checkbox or button ;)

**Create a new VPC**

I find it's best to leave the default VPC alone, so you don't take the risk of breaking something that's already working in that VPC (in case you already have resources there), and also because you can use the default VPC as configuration reference in the future.

Use the wizard for creating the VPC.

[image]

**Create the Route Tables**

1. Name the first `public-subnet` (if it's not already there);
2. Name the second `private-lambda`. AWS support recommends having a separate subnet just for the lambda, and this Route Table is going to be attached to it.

[image]

**Create the subnets**

By default, when you create a VPC, it will create a public subnet for you. If you used default values, its name should be `Public subnet`. Leave it at that.

Now you are going to create the private subnets. Is recommended to have several private subnets for your Lambda if you want it to have high availability.

Each of these private subnets will be linked to the VPC you just created. Now, supposing you left the VPC IP as `10.0.0.0/16`, and that you run your resources in Virginia (`us-east-1`), here is a template for creating six private subnets, each in a different availability zone (for high availability):

1. `private-lambda-us-east-1a`, availability zone `us-east-1a`, IP block `10.0.16.0/24`
2. `private-lambda-us-east-1b`, availability zone `us-east-1b`, IP block `10.0.32.0/24`
3. `private-lambda-us-east-1c`, availability zone `us-east-1c`, IP block `10.0.48.0/24`
4. `private-lambda-us-east-1d`, availability zone `us-east-1d`, IP block `10.0.64.0/24`
5. `private-lambda-us-east-1e`, availability zone `us-east-1e`, IP block `10.0.80.0/24`
6. `private-lambda-us-east-1f`, availability zone `us-east-1f`, IP block `10.0.92.0/24`

But you can see the pattern:
- There's a 16 increment in the 3rd position of the IP block;
- The names indicate the selected availability zone in your region.

[image]

**Ensure Route Table vs Subnet associations**

- Go to the Route Tables panel;
- Select the public-subnet table, review its associations and make sure it's associated to the Public Subnet;
- Select the private-lambda table, review its associations and make sure It's associated to all the `private-lambda-*` subnets you just created.

[image]

**Create an Internet Gateway**

Just create one and attach it to the VPC.

**Configure the routes for the Public Subnet**

In my case it came configured, but just make sure that the Route Table for your Public Subnet has an entry from `0.0.0.0/0` to your just-created Internet Gateway.

[image]

**Create a NAT (network address translator)**

Create a new NAT and select your Public Subnet. Allocate a new EIP.

**Configure the routes for the Private Subnets**

Ensure that the Route Table for your Private Subnets has an entry from `0.0.0.0/0` to your new NAT.

[image]

And with these steps, you should now have an Internet-enabled VPC.

---

#### Use Case: configuring a Lambda for internet and RDS access

**Create a Security Group for the lambda**

- New up a SG and configure Outbound -> All Trafic -> to `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0`

**Modify the Security Group of your RDS instance to allow**

- Inbound -> All trafic -> from the lambda SG

**Configure the lambda**

- Create a new lambda or select an existing one;
- Select your new VPC;
- Select all your private subnets (`private-lambda-*`) for high availability;
- Select your lambda Security Group.

And that's it. You should now have a lambda function that can access both VPC and Internet resources :)

Comment: I devised this method from this page: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: I have used same approach but not able to connect

Comment: Tried exactly same steps ! Works like charm

Comment: This had me struggling a year ago, if only this guide wouldve existed back then. Works perfectly

Comment: What if i need to connect to something in default VPC, say a EC2 DB server? and the internet ofcourse

Comment: Dineshs91 I don't know a way to solve this w/o a NAT. Also, the official guidance from AWS, which I used as a base for this solution, has NAT all over it. You can find a link to the article in my first comment, above.

Comment: An upvote for you sir, thank you. This worked like a charm. I wish AWS would lay it out as simple as this. Much appreciated.

Comment: It  took me hours trying to figure it out, many thanks

Comment: That seems accurate, but there are so many pitfalls for someone not laser focussed: for the Lambda configuration, only private subnet shall be selected (like mentioned) - selecting public subnets for the Lambda *will* cause local connection to VPC resources to fail (somehow) - more is not better (!). The NAT Gateway shall be created in the public subnet but be in the private route table ... while the Internet Gateway shall be in the public route table (... :-) )

Comment: I came here to upvote this because you literally saved my coworkers life.

Comment: In the decade that I've been using stackoverflow, this answer is by far the one I am the most grateful for. I never never would have been able to come up with this on my own, but this answer stepped me through each and every step. Thank you so much.

Comment: why do we need NAT? can't we just create an internet gateway, add it to the main routing table and use public subnets in lambda?

Comment: also why do we need to make NAT public and assign EIP to it, if it is still going to route the traffic to public subnet which in turn is connected to internet gateway?

Answer (score 12):

I found the error, the NAT Gateway should be added to a public subnet (not a private one).
A public subnet is the subnet with the Internet Gatway route associated to `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: That default route more properly be would be expressed as `0.0.0.0/0`.

Answer (score 9):

Since I faced the same issue adding a bit more clarity to the above answer -

1. Add NAT Gateway or NAT instance to public subnet (the one that has an 
   `0.0.0.0/0` entry to internet gateway in corresponding (public) subnets route table)
2. Edit route table of private subnet (where you are running your lambda) to have an entry for `0.0.0.0/0` to the NAT gateway in the public subnet.
3. Make sure security group assigned to lambda allows outbound connections.

Comment: When i do this, it has a status of 'blackhole'.

Comment: I think that means the NAT Gateway has been deleted

Answer (score 4):

If you are to do this with Terraform, here are the resources that you will need to configure (in addition to Lambda resources):

- `aws_vpc`
- `aws_subnet` (public and private; multiple for high availability)
- `aws_internet_gateway` for outbound connection to the internet
- `aws_route_table` (x2 for public and private subnets)
- `aws_route_table_association`
- `aws_eip` (Elastic IP for the NAT Gateway)
- `aws_nat_gateway`
- `aws_default_network_acl` to manage the default NACL with Terraform
- `aws_default_security_group` to manage the default Security Group with Terraform
- `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` to attach `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` policy

[Deploy AWS Lambda to VPC with Terraform](https://www.maxivanov.io/deploy-aws-lambda-to-vpc-with-terraform/).

Answer (score 3):

> If you need both, then I'll have to set up the VPC for internet access, which is a mess (hey AWS guys, if you have a well-defined process for it, please make it simple: turn it into a checkbox or button ;)

Your prayers have been heard and AWS now has an "Resources to create" -> "VPC, subnets, etc." option when creating a new VPC where you can just choose the amount of subnets, AZs, NAT Gateways etc. in the wizard and it creates everything you described for you:
[Create VPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7NtZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

For the ease if you are starting use the VPC launch template on the VPC home page to deploy the VPC. This will create public subnet, private subnet, NAT GW, IGW and all the required routes to access internet from private subnet.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to access the Secrets Manager after adding the Lambda function to a VPC. On this thread it discusses a NAT solution but also using a VPC endpoint:
[AWS Lambda access Secrets Manager from within VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274069/aws-lambda-access-secrets-manager-from-within-vpc)

More information:
[Access an AWS service using an interface VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html#create-interface-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the Lambda outside a `VPC` (having internet access), but you still need a specific service from the VPC, then you can follow my recommendation:

Some services like `ElastiCache` (which was my case) will not be able to be exposed publicly, no matter how *public* you make your VPC, because that's how it was designed.

But there is a workaround which I managed to use it successfully for achieving that.

You can use a `EC2` instance deployed in that VPC (being it even private) and act as a *bastion*.

You'll need to use `socat` to make your `EC2` instance to act as a reverse-proxy.

---

**Steps:**

1. Install socat:

`sudo yum install -y socat`

2. Run socat to forward traffic from the EC2 instance to the Redis cluster (update `redis-host` with your Redis Cluster host from AWS):

`sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:6379,fork,reuseaddr TCP:redis-host:6379 &`

That's all.

---

Extra:
**Persisting across reboots:**

1. Create a systemd service for socat:
   `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/socat-redis.service`
2. Add the following to the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Socat Redis Forwarding
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat TCP-LISTEN:6379,fork,reuseaddr TCP:redis-demo.v4422l.clustercfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
Restart=always
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Enable and start the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable socat-redis
sudo systemctl start socat-redis
```

This will ensure that the socat process starts on boot and will attempt to restart if it dies for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I resolve my similar case

1 : add your Lambda function to public subnet of your VPC

if you check your network interface list, you are going to find the related interface added to your public subnet

2 : add a security policy with inbound and outbound letting all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0

3 : create an elastic IP

4 : associate this elastic Ip to the Lambda function interface (listed in network interfaces section)

and now you have the internet for your function