# Lambda function timeout on external call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function from which I need to make an external API call. I have added the Lambda function to a security group, a VPC, and 2 subnets, and it gives me this text:

> When you enable VPC, your Lambda function will lose default internet
>   access. If you require external internet access for your function,
>   ensure that your security group allows outbound connections and that
>   your VPC has a NAT gateway.

I go into VPC, create a NAT gateway (I let AWS create a EIP), attach it to one of the subnets on my lambda function.

For debugging purposes, my security group outbound functions are set to all traffic/all destinations (`0.0.0.0/0`). Also my Network ACL for this VPC is set to this (with 5 subnets, including the one with the NAT gateway):

```
100 | ALL Traffic | ALL | ALL | 0.0.0.0/0 | ALLOW
```

A route table with the same 2 subnets is on the VPC, with the `0.0.0.0/0` route set to target the NAT gateway.

A different route table with 3 other subnets is also on the VPC, with the `0.0.0.0/0` route set to target the internet gateway.

Both route tables have the same `local` destination IP (the IP for the VPC).

The error I get is:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: 'x.x.x.x',
port: 443 }
```

The node code I am running works on my desktop node environment, and the POST call works in postman, so I am fairly certain this is problem with my AWS config.

I have been using this scenario as a resource: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Comment: Could it be that security groups blocking something? and it seems NAT gateway should be attached to public subnet, is that how you configured it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135725/aws-lambda-connecting-to-internet?rq=1

Comment: I added a link to the resource I've been using. I created the VPC using the wizard with public/private just to make sure everything is setup correctly. Changed out to the new VPC in my lambda function, added the new private+public subnet + security group. Security group has all outbound connections set to 0.0.0.0/0. Still ETIMEDOUT. I must be missing something, but not sure how to debug...

Comment: One question, all resources are in same region or different region?

Comment: all are in N. VA.

Comment: Did you follow the security groups section in the link you have specified? ACL & AWS Security groups?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I go into VPC, create a NAT gateway (I let AWS create a EIP), attach it to one of the subnets on my lambda function.

That is where gou went wrong.

The NAT Gateway must **not** be attached to any of the subnets it serves.  The NAT Gateway must be on a public subnet with a default route to the Internet Gateway.

A NAT Gateway's default route follows the default route of the route table of the subnet to which it is attached, to reach the Internet.  If it's associated with a subnet that needs a NAT Gatway, its default route loops back on itself.

Then, *all* subnets associated with Lambda need to use a route table whose default route points to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: Oh man, yeah I read that doc again and it seems so clear now. Once more, without the oops...