# AWS Lambda timeout when calling AWS service after MySQL query using Serverless

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm working with some business code that handles a given event, queries a MySQL DB and  then uploads a formatted object to DynamoDB. The code looks like this:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
});

module.exports.handle = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  console.time("query");

  // more code

  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) callback(Error(`could not get a pool connection: ${err}`));

    connection.query(query, (err, res, fields) => {
      connection.release();
      if (err) {
        callback(Error(`could not execute query: ${err}`));
      } else {
        console.timeEnd("query");
        console.time("parsing");

        // more code

        let inputItem = {
          Item: item,
          TableName: "some_table"
        }

        console.timeEnd("parsing");
        console.time("putItem");

        // here it hangs... no err, no data

        dynamodb.putItem(inputItem, function (err, data) {
          if (err) callback(Error(`could not putItem: ${err}`))
          console.timeEnd("putItem");
          callback(null, JSON.stringify({
            message: "OK"
          }));
        });

      }
    });
  });
}
```

I used Serverless to bundle this code and deployed it to AWS.
When I execute the lambda locally using `sls invoke local` it works, but when I try to run the deployed one (either from `sls` or the AWS console) I get a timeout every time.

It's REALLY strange, because if I delete the MySQL code it works, i.e. it puts the item to DynamoDB. In fact the original code was a Go lambda. With that code I had exactly the same error, when calling one AWS service: no problem, when calling MySQL and then a AWS service, hangs... Tried all different version of Go, AWS-SDK packages, etc... Decided to migrate it to Node, thinking it's a Go problem. I don't really know what's going on...

In terms of roles and permissions, they are OK, as I said, the code WORK if I only call a AWS service during the Lambda execution.

Any ideas on what could be wrong, or if I'm just an idiot missing something?

I guess the unique solution will be to chain Lambdas...

Comment: Where is your MySQL server running?  Is it RDS?  Ultimately it sounds like there is a firewall type of issue preventing Lambda from connecting to MySQL.

Comment: No, I don´t have problems connecting to the SQL. The DB is in RDS inside a VPC. The lambda has it´s sec group and all, so it can connect to it.

Comment: What does it mean "call a AWS service during the Lambda execution"? How you can call it outside of Lambda execution?

Comment: I mean just calling DynamoDB, or Eventbridge, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some research and found out that this is realed on how the VPC is configured. I turns out that the Lambda does not have access to the internet from within the VPC, so you need to either:

1. Configure a DB Proxy (not recommended for production as it's in beta preview) and make the connection to the DB via this.
2. Configure the VPC to have access to the internet.

Sources:

- AWS Guide: [Grant internet access to a lambda fucntion](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)
- Stack Overflow related: [Lambda function within VPC doesn't have access to public Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276852/lambda-function-within-vpc-doesnt-have-access-to-public-internet)
- Stack Overflow related: [Lambda function timeout on external call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661156/lambda-function-timeout-on-external-call)