Axios always times out in Lambda
I have the following code in Lambda that calls an API via Axios that returns a dummy JSON output.  This code works perfectly from my local machine, however, when running from Lambda, it always times out when executing the Axios call:
const axios = require('axios');
async function testAxios() {

  let result;
  console.log("START");
  try {
    let response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    result = await response.data;
  } catch (errors) {
    result = "ERROR: " + errors;
  }
  console.log("END: " + JSON.stringify(result));
  return result;

}

This is the expected output I get when running from my local machine:
START
END: {"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false}
{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},"body":"{\"userId\":1,\"id\":1,\"title\":\"delectus aut autem\",\"completed\":false}"}

This is the unexpected output I get when running from Lambda where it times out after 10 seconds:
START RequestId: d9ad29e3-858a-47a8-a86d-35fc16704b55 Version: $LATEST
2024-05-08T21:24:00.420Z    d9ad29e3-858a-47a8-a86d-35fc16704b55    INFO    START
2024-05-08T21:24:10.432Z d9ad29e3-858a-47a8-a86d-35fc16704b55 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds

Other information:

Nodejs: 18.x
Axios: 1.6.8
VPC Inbound/Outbound: All (0.0.0.0/0)
Lambda timeout: 10 seconds (I've tried 30 seconds but get the same results)

Any suggestions to resolve this would be appreciated!

See here - it sounds like the lambda lost internet access because of the connection to the VPC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135725/aws-lambda-connecting-to-internet

UPDATE: After researching IAmCoder's comment, I was able to resolve this by following these steps in AWS to connect my NAT gateway & subnets to the Internet.
