# Alexa custom skill with ask-dsk-v2 for Node.js. Query to Mysql on RDS fail, return empty

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, alexa-skills-kit

Hello, I am doing a "custom skill - provision your own" (*not used alexa-hosted-based*) using ask-dsk-v2 on node.js and I want to basic query a table that is in a MySql in RDS. Lamba function and RDS are in eu-west-1 (Ireland). Lambda and ask CLI used Runtime Node.js 10.x.

My function **getPrimero()** is executed when done Test on Alexa Dev Console, **but return empty on "ssml":** "" (see below JSON Output 1).

**NOTE:** If executed alone function **getPrimero()** on local node.js (on my PC)  the query works and return the data of the table of Mysql on RDS (below):

```
MySql query on RDS Succees!, the result:  Ensalada de Bogavante
```

About config of RDS:

- Public accessibility: YES
- IAM DB authentication: DISABLE

About Lambda:

- Virtual Private Cloud (VPC): NO VPC
- trigger: Alexa Skill Kit (asociated ID alexa skill)

About the IAM permission:

- This step is confuse for my ( I´ve not found the exact doc to applied). I´ve applied this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html

**About the problem, my questions:**

- IAM permissions, Lambda / RDS configuration or code, what may be failing on alexa custom skill?
- How can you easily test a query and connection (to discover what fail) to MySql in RDS?
- Has anyone successfully managed a query to Mysql in RDS with nodejs and alexa custom skill and ask-sdk-v2 on nodejs?

Any help is welcome!

Thank you in advance!

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const i18n = require('i18next');
var config = require('./db_config.json');
var mysql = require('mysql');
const utf8 = require('utf8');
var Promise = require('promise');
var async = require("async");

const PrimerosIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'PrimerosIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        var  speakOutput = await getPrimero();
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt('¿Quieres saber algún plato más?')
            .withShouldEndSession(false)
            .getResponse();
    }
};


const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        const speakOutput = "Perdona, no entiendo lo que dices. Por favor prueba de nuevo";
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

> My function , just below the above code "const PrimerosIntentHandler{..}"  :

```
function getPrimero(){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host            : config.dbhost,
        user            : config.dbuser,
        password        : config.dbpassword,
        database        : config.dbname
    });

    connection.connect(async function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack); // show error, if happen
        return;
        }
        // if no error, to do the query:
        //console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId); // ONLY TEST
        var sqlQuery =  "SELECT nombre FROM r_menus WHERE site=342800010 AND es_un='Primeros'";
        var returnValue = "";
        returnValueFinal = "";
        connection.query(sqlQuery, function(error, rows) {
            if (error) {
                returnValue = "An error on connection.query";
            } else {
                returnValue = utf8.decode(rows[0]['nombre']); // also: rows[1]['nombre'] ; rows[2]['nombre']
                console.log("MySql query on RDS Success!, the result: " + returnValue);
                return (returnValue);
            }
        }); // .connection.query()
        connection.end();
    }); // .connection.connect() 
};
```

Alexa JSON Output 1  ( "response":, outputSpeech":, "ssml": """ ) is empty:

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak></speak>"
            },
            "reprompt": {
                "outputSpeech": {
                    "type": "SSML",
                    "ssml": "<speak>¿Quieres saber algun plato más?</speak>"
                }
            },
            "shouldEndSession": false,
            "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-node/2.7.0 Node/v10.17.0 sample/hello-world/v1.2"
    }
}
```

CloudWatch output when to do Test on Lambda function (executed my code of "ErrorHandler{..}"):

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "SSML",
      "ssml": "<speak>Perdona, no entiendo lo que dices. Por favor prueba de nuevo</speak>"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": "<speak>Perdona, no entiendo lo que dices. Por favor prueba de nuevo</speak>"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  },
  "userAgent": "ask-node/2.7.0 Node/v10.17.0 sample/hello-world/v1.2"
}

START RequestId: 21685e97-1537-4017-a8a7-734961bfbed1 Version: $LATEST
2020-01-08T13:46:34.556Z    21685e97-1537-4017-a8a7-734961bfbed1    INFO    ~~~~ Error handled: {}
END RequestId: 21685e97-1537-4017-a8a7-734961bfbed1
REPORT RequestId: 21685e97-1537-4017-a8a7-734961bfbed1  Duration: 25.47 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 88 MB
```

Comment: Hey I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52037430) may help you.

Comment: I going to follow step-by-step your link. I´ll tell you ... Thnks!