# Can't access to RDS from Amazon Lambda, same VPC and correct role permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, serverless-framework

I can't successfully connect to RDS from Amazon Lambda in production.
For Amazon Lambda I'm using Serverless framework, executing sls offline I can connect with RDS from localhost, but in production Amazon Lambda doesn't.

Both are in same VPC, in same security group, that has all traffic inbound access, and a rule that is pointing to Vpc's CIDR.

I have these permissions attached: AmazonRDSFullAccess, AWSLambdaFullAccess, AmazonVPCFullAccess, AWSLambdaExecute and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow AWS Lambda to access RDS Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030704/allow-aws-lambda-to-access-rds-database)

Comment: I followed all the indications, but I could not make the connection work, I guess this is another error.

Comment: How about this ? 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-create-iam-role.html

Comment: I have these permissions attached:  AmazonRDSFullAccess,  AWSLambdaFullAccess,  AmazonVPCFullAccess,  AWSLambdaExecute and  AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole but still not working.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: Description updated with: Both are in same VPC, in same security group, that has all traffic inbound access, and a rule that is pointing to Vpc's CIDR.

Comment: @fabian818 I was struggling with this myself recently. Could you provide your serverless.yml? also, what errors are you seeing in your lambda's Cloudwatch logs?

Comment: it is your permission. Try to put rds and Lambda in some vpc/security group and subset. If your rds is public, your lambda subnet should have internet to access it.

Comment: If my RDS Is public I need a NAT? No other way to access that resource in the same VPC?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this issue and the following is a summary of the steps I took to resolve:

1. In lambda network section select the VPC and all subnets. Set the security group to the security group the RDS was created with / set to.
2. Edit said security group inbound policies and set a policy with RDS port/access settings and set the source equal to its own Group Id. It is not sufficient that they are in the same group, if it doesn't accept connections from it's own group.
3. Ensure the lambda function execution role has AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole and AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policies attached.

Good luck.

Comment: After hours of searching this looks like exactly what is needed. However it still doesn't work. After some head scratching I went to use the query editor in RDS and my admin credentials aren't working! So my guess is the problem is with the RDS setup, not with Lambda.

Comment: Apparently the password for my master account (username: admin) was incorrect ... Fixing that allowed me to connect to the query editor. After verifying the query editor worked the Lambda code worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change "IAM DB Authentication Enabled" to YES on your database and apply changes immediately so you don't wait for maintenance.

That solved my problem.