# How to connect Lambda in VPC to RDS?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-vpc

There are multiple questions/answers for this but none of the solutions seem to work.

- [How to properly connect AWS Lambda to RDS in VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534740/how-to-properly-connect-aws-lambda-to-rds-in-vpc)
- [Allow AWS Lambda to access RDS Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030704/allow-aws-lambda-to-access-rds-database)
- [Can't access to RDS from Amazon Lambda, same VPC and correct role permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991897/cant-access-to-rds-from-amazon-lambda-same-vpc-and-correct-role-permissions)

My current setup is:

- Lambda (with python 2.7 runtime) in VPC
- RDS instance (postgres) in same VPC
- Lambda role has policy read/write to certain S3 buckets and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
- Lambda subnet's route table has access to local IPs, and to a VPC endpoint for S3
- RDS subnet's route table has access to local IPs
- Lambda security group (SG) has inbound & outbound rules for Postgres & VPC endpoint
- RDS SG has inbound & outbound rules for the Lambda SG id

I'm using psycopg2 to connect, which is in my `requirements.txt` file. I tried a simple SELECT query as below:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=os.environ['DB_NAME'], user=os.environ['USERNAME'], password=os.environ['PASSWORD'])
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * from {};".format(os.environ['TABLE'])
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

Which gives me the error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
: OperationalError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/mylambda.py", line 31, in call
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=os.environ['DB_NAME'], 
user=os.environ['USERNAME'], password=os.environ['PASSWORD'])
File "/tmp/sls-py-req/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
```

What am I missing? How can I successfully connect to RDS from my Lambda?
Thanks!

Comment: If you run this on an EC2 instance in the same subnet as the Lambda function and with the same SG, can you connect?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show values for `host` or `port` in the `connect()` call. Did you simply not copy them into the question, or are they not present in your actual code?

Comment: @kdgregory oh gosh you're right! I'll add it in and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @kdgregory that was it! I was looking at it for far too long and completely missed it. I even had host included in my environment variables but didn't think that it was missing in my code. Thanks!

Comment: @Katherine, the giveaway here was in the error message... `Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?` ...this gives you two pieces of information that indicate your code was not trying to connect to a separate server:  "Is the server running locally?" You weren't trying to connect to a local server, you were trying to connect to a remote one... and a  *"unix domain socket"* never connects you to a different machine, only the local one.

Comment: That makes perfect sense @Michael-sqlbot, thank you for that explanation.