# AWS Lambda NodeJS call to SQL Server returns no data and no errors

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to an AWS hosted SQL server with a lambda function, but when I test it in the lambda management console, or via an API call I get passed all the way through the function to get the final response of `test here`

This seems to indicate that the call hit no errors and returned no records. Since I know the table has data I would have at least expected an error or ideally, data. How can I troubleshoot this?

using CloudWatch console output I see 'called rdsquery' but nothing after that point

```
var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
var config = {
    user: 'xxuser',
    password: 'xxxx',
    server: 'mydns', 
    database: 'Antonio' 
};


module.exports.rdsquery = async event => {

console.log('called rdsquery')
  try{
    // connect to your database
    await sql.connect(config, function (err) {

      console.log('connected')
        if (err) 
          console.log('rdsquery: '+err)
          //return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify('sql connect err: '+err)};

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        console.log('rdsquery: request crated')   
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select CustomerNo from FROMMAS_AR_Customer', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err)
            console.log('rdsquery-sql: '+err)   
            //return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify('sql err: '+err)};

            // send records as a response
            console.log('logging recordset')
            console.log(recordset);
            return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify(recordset)};
            //return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify(recordset)};
        });
    });
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    console.log('rdsquery-catch: '+e)   
    return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify('ERR: '+e)};
  }

  //return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify('test here')};
};
```

Comment: did you check AWS cloudwatch logs? you should console error instead of return them to help in debug

Comment: @Adiii I added console logs to my code, and it appears like the connection is never being established and failing invisibly

Comment: Where is the ms server? Is it accessible from lambda?

Comment: Assuming `rdsquery` is your handler function, wouldn't you still need to call the Lambda handler's `callback` somehow?

Comment: Yes, after some more digging (when I put the `require mssql` inside the try catch) I get a 'module not found error'. Seems like im not loading it into lambda correctly

Comment: First thing, the handler is missing in your code I was able to catch when I run it on my Side.
dont have MSSQL to test but tested below code using mysql its working.
```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'sdb.test.com',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'test'
});

connection.connect();

exports.handler = (event, context) => {

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err, rows, fields) {
        console.log("rows: " + rows);
        context.succeed('Success');
    });

};
```

Comment: @Adiii My code is using Microsoft SQL Server, not mysql

Comment: I know I mentioned I don't have MS sql so just for example

Comment: Check in your CloudWatch, do you see any error like `timed out`? Maybe your code takes to long time to connect to mssql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE THAT I AM NOT A LAMBDA EXPERT. Any of this info could be totally wrong. I would appreciate comments below if you find issues with how I solved the problem**

So after a lot of digging I found that I had several problems with my lambda configuration:

1. My Lambda function timeout was too short by default. When I increased the timeout to 30 seconds I started getting useful errors like `Could not connect MYIP` when I ran tests inside lambda.
2. Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41190185/1634753) on SO which had me add a VPC to my lambda function (so the function could access RDS)
3. Finally I had to add the policy `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` to my lambda user.