# Not getting any console readings from AWS Lambda when trying to connect to RDS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-postgres

I'm trying to verify that I'm able to connect to my RDS database, but nothing is logged in the connection promise / callback. I was able to connect from my local machine, but not on AWS. I'm out of ideas on how else I can debug this as I've done everything I can find online.

I've verified that the RDS instance and Lambda function in the same VPC, VPC security group, and subnets as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030704/allow-aws-lambda-to-access-rds-database#:%7E:text=You%20can%20configure%20Lambda%20to,you%20need%20it%20to%20access.). For that VPC security group, I've added `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0`, and the inbound rules can be seen below:
[image]

The RDS instance is set to be publicly accessible, and setting to not publicly accessible doesn't make a difference. Below is the output I get from running the lambda function.

```
START RequestId: 9567a1be-d8d1-4b61-b9c4-4dd06ff36a4b Version: $LATEST
2021-07-21T23:52:47.115Z    9567a1be-d8d1-4b61-b9c4-4dd06ff36a4b    INFO    Lambda invoked
END RequestId: 9567a1be-d8d1-4b61-b9c4-4dd06ff36a4b
REPORT RequestId: 9567a1be-d8d1-4b61-b9c4-4dd06ff36a4b  Duration: 52.71 ms  Billed Duration: 53 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 71 MB  Init Duration: 193.40 ms
```

I'm using the pg code I got from the node-postgres [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling). I went through the Amazon [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html) for connecting lambda function to rds,  giving it a role with `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` (I didn't use the CLI as they have, I used the GUI on the website). I also read that the console object inside promises don't always return, so I've wrapped every promise in a try catch block and still nothing is returned.

```js
const {Client, Pool} = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'myusername', 
  password: 'mypassword', 
  host: 'blahblah.somestuff.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 
  port: 5432, 
  database: 'postgres'
})

pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
  console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err)
  process.exit(-1)
})


exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  console.log('Lambda invoked') // this logs just fine
  
  try {
    var client = pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('connected')
      try {
        client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [1], (err, res) => {
          done()
          console.log('query has run')
          if (err) {
            throw err;
            // console.log(err.stack)
          } else {
            console.log(res.rows[0])
          }
        })
      } catch(err) {
        throw err
      }
    })
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
};
```

Node-postgres 6.4.2, PostgreSQL 12.6R1

Comment: Why does the log not show an error message? Your code seems to be catching all error situations.

Answer (score 0):

The proper configuration of the Security Groups would be:

- A **Security Group on the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`) with default settings of Allow All Outbound
- A **Security Group on the Amazon RDS database** (`DB-SG`) with an Inbound rule that permits traffic from `Lambda-SG` on port 5432 (for PostgreSQL)

That is, `DB-SG` specifically references `Lambda-SG` as permissible for inbound traffic. This is much cleaner than putting resources "in the same Security Group", which is an incorrect model because Security Groups apply to each resource individually.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm simply trying to get started by following the AWS documentation for connecting Lambda with RDS, which uses the same security group I believe: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html. I don't see any reason why they would provide documentation that fails to work out of the gate.

Comment: That document does not describe Security Group configuration. It is worth doing the above because it _might_ fix your problem, and it is a more specific definition of the security permissions rather than relying on co-membership of an existing Security Group.

Comment: I created two new security groups. Lambda-SG with Outbound Rule `IPv4`, All traffic, All protocol, All ports, with destination `0.0.0.0/0` and no Inbound Rules. I also made DB-SG with Inbound Rule type PostgreSQL, TCP protocol, 5432 port range, and source `Lambda-SG` , with Outbound Rule set to default (IPv4 all traffic, all protocol, all ports, destination `0.0.0.0/0`). It's not logging anything, as before.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. My version of `pg` was not compatible with the version of node that Lambda was running. Sorry for the fuss, and I appreciate the help!